# How can I display the nickname from the database in the textview?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, android-studio, textview

I know it kinda easy though ive been struggling since im new to the programming industry. I dont know how should I display the nickname from the database which it is already which is already stored in there. The problem is how can I display that nickname to a textview?

Here is my code from my **DataBaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.laseenem;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LaSEENem.db"; // DATABASE for LASEENEM
    private static final int DATA_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NICKNAME = "tbl_nickname"; //  TABLE for nickname

//    TABLE NICKNAME columns
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    private static final String COLUMN_NICKNAME = "Nickname";

    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATA_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NICKNAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NICKNAME + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NICKNAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void insertNickname(String nickname){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_NICKNAME, nickname);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NICKNAME, null, cv);
        if (result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to LaSEEnem!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    Cursor displayNickname(){
        String query = "SELECT " + TABLE_NICKNAME +" WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = 1";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if (db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

I want to show the nickname to the nickname variable(Textview).

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        DATABASE_NICKNAME = new DatabaseHelper(Dashboard.this);

        //I want to display to this view from the query
        nickname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nickname);
```

Comment: Your database helper should not have a method like `displayNickname`.  It should have a method like `fetchNickname` that RETURNs a nickname based on an ID, but it is the responsibility of your GUI class to take the returned string and display it.

Comment: So how should i do it correctly?

Comment: As I said, you'd have a `fetchNickname` function that takes an ID as a parameter, does the lookup, and returns the nickname.